# Cambiar BackGround de Textbox desde Javascript

Tags: javascript, webforms

¿Alguna forma de cambiar el color de fondo de un `asp:Textbox` con el evento `OnClientClick` de un `asp:Button` desde `JavaScript` sin usar:

```
document.getElementById("un_textbox").style.background = '#f88067';
```

El boton esta definido de la sigueinte manera:

```
 <asp:Button ID="re" runat="server" autopostback="True" OnClick="re_Click"  OnClientClick="return comprueba();" style="height: 32px" Text="Registrate" />
```

Comment: estas asignando el valor `'color'`... se supone que es una variable ? Iria sin comillas

Comment: Bueno, ese 'color' es solo es un ejemplo generico, yo estoy atinando a: '#f88067'. Y con backgroundColor no me corrio :c

Comment: Ah, ok. Mejor, así descartamos problemas. Has probado a hacer un `console.log` de ese textbox?  para ver que lo estás cogiendo bien

Comment: Muestranos la definicion de la funcion que tienes en el evento `OnClientClick`

Comment: No, la verdad no se como se aplica. Donde y como aplico eso?

Comment: Quiza pasando parametros como el id del textbox y recibirlos desde la funcion en javascript?

Comment: Para hacer eso, es obligatorio hacer lo que no quieres que se haga.

Comment: Tenias razon con lo de que era obligatorio hacerlo de alguna de las dos formas. Probe con la primera pero añadiendo el script inmediatamente despues de <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">  y me funciono :D Es solo que antes no me daba, ahora no recuerdo porque. Pero bueno, gracias a todos por aportar. Edita la respuesta, pues, borre lo del div, como si no hubiera mencionado que no podia hacerlo de las formas que dije.

Comment: Hola @Necroyeti van varias preguntas que etiquetas con [tag:asp.net-mvc-5] y no es la tecnología que estás usando. La tecnología que usas es [tag:webforms], ambas pertencen a .Net pero son tecnologías diferentes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La unica forma en que pude lograrlo es declarando una variable js, asignarle el id del `div` y luego pasarle como parametro la variable a la funcion:

```
<script>
   var id = "<%= txtBuscar.ClientID  %>";
</script>
<asp:Button OnClientClick='return comprueba(id)' runat="server" Text="Comprobar"/>
```

Y en tu archivo js:

```
   function comprueba(divId)
   {
      docuement.getElementById(divId).style.background = "red";
      return false;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que dejes de renegar con javascript puro e instales alguna libreria como JQuery de paso forma alternativa y no tan engorrosa.

Por lo general los elementos ASPX al dibujarse en HTML terminan con el ID cambiado

```
<asp:Button ID="re" runat="server" autopostback="True" OnClick="re_Click"  OnClientClick="return comprueba();" style="height: 32px" Text="Registrate" />
```

por lo que una llamada por ejemplo para instanciar ese boton via id, colocandolo tal cual se nombro no funcionaria:

```
$("#re")
```

pero en cambio podes usar una pseudo expresion regular para matchearlo para que funcione.

```
$("[id$='re']")
```

dicho esto dado un textbox digamos el siguiente, si es un componente html cualquiera de las dos formas funcionara si es un componente asp usa la segunda para referenciar, y para cambiar el color de fondo seria:

```
 $("#elementId").css('background-color', "#f00000")
```

en fin un ejemplo usando jquery:

```js
function cambiarColor(elementId) {
  $('#' + elementId).css('background-color', '#F00');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="textbox">
<button type="button" onclick="cambiarColor('textbox')">cambiar color</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

debes acceder al id de tu div

```js
function changeColor() {
  document.getElementById("un_textbox").style.backgroundColor = 'RED';
}

changeColor();
```

```html
<div id="un_textbox">hola mundo</div>
```

Comment: Pero cambia es el color de div, no del Textbox :c